# Betareg for bounded variable

Tags: regression, linear-regression, logistic-regression, bounded-types

my dependent variable is bounded between 0 and 1, and I am concerned that OLS estimates could be biased. I planned to use betareg function; it seems to run but when I ask for a summary my computer crashes. Has anyone experienced this problem? Alternatively, could you suggest some other function, which also uses a logit - type transformation, but works more reliably?